# A problem with download Three.js and gltf loader

Tags: javascript

> Mistake: Uncaught `TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier
> "three". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or
> "../".

Please tell me what the problem is, the question is probably very stupid, but I couldn't figure it out myself.

```
import * as THREE from 'https://unpkg.com/three@0.126.1/build/three.module.js';
import { GLTFLoader } from
    'https://unpkg.com/three@0.128.0/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
const loader = new GLTFLoader();
loader.load('Capblend.glb', function (gltf) {
    scene.add(gltf.scene);
}, undefined, function (error) {
    console.error(error);
});

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
animate();
```